# Laravel: Get data with custom date

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get data in laravel like this:

```
level: SMP
year: 2020
month: Jan - May
value : 46

level: SD
year: 2020
month: Feb-Apr
value : 23
```

Where "the value" is the number of students for that month. How to display data ( especially in the month part )? I tried it, but it returns like this:

[image: this]

this is my code :

[image: code]

Edit :

I want to make data with the same year and same level into one for example,
before :

```
level: SD
year: 2021
month: Jan
value : 2

level: SD
year: 2021
month: Feb
value : 1

level: SD
year: 2021
month: Mar
value : 4

level: SMP
year: 2020
month: Feb
value: 10
```

after :

```
level: SD
year: 2021
month: Jan - Mar
value : 7

level: SMP
year: 2020
month: Feb
value: 10
```

Comment: show an example what you want to get

Comment: because I want to export data to pdf in table form

Comment: ok, ok i got what you need

Comment: how do you store the month in the database? what type is it

Comment: Please add your images as text so that if the image is deleted your question is still understandable.

Comment: @AlexBlack the month column is "created_at" and the type is "timestamp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This groups by level and aggregates the month:
SQL:

```sql
$students = DB::table('students')->select(
    DB::raw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade,' ',-1) AS level"),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(students.created_at, '%Y') as year"),
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(students.created_at, "%m") as month'),
    DB::raw('CAST(count(*) AS CHAR)as value')
)
    ->whereNotNull('grade')
    ->groupBy('level', 'year')
    ->orderBy('level','ASC')
    ->orderBy('year','ASC')
    ->get();
return $students;
```

```php
/*$monthNum = function ($entry) {
  return Carbon\Carbon::parse('1 '.$entry->month)->month;
};*/

$students = $students->groupBy('level', 'year')->map(function($group, $level)/* use($monthNum)*/ {
  return (object)[
    "level" => $level,
    "year" => $group[0]->year,
    //"month" => date("M",mktime(0,0,0,$group->min($monthNum),1,date('Y')))." \u{2012} ".date("M",mktime(0,0,0,$group->max($monthNum),1,date('Y'))),
    "month" => date("M",mktime(0,0,0,$group->min(),1,date('Y')))." \u{2012} ".date("M",mktime(0,0,0,$group->max(),1,date('Y'))),
    "value"  => $group[0]->value
  ];
})->values();
```

Comment: it is bad. Why not use sql query ?

Comment: Just because it's not _your_ solution, that doesn't make mine bad. Because your solution lists ALL months instead of - as requested by the TO - the first and the last month

Comment: when I wrote the answer, the question was not clarified. I believe that the sql version will work much faster with a large amount of data

Comment: Think it is better to apply groupBy on both level and year, beside aggregating the first and last month of each, then transform the the month in that form.

Comment: @AlexBlack I agree that it's faster _if_ you _can_ solve a problem directly with SQL but in this case it doesn't seem to work solely with SQL.

Comment: @MohsenNazari By the way, fyi: I added your suggestions.

Comment: Hello @shaedrich, I try this code. But it got error result "Undefined variable $monthNum"

Comment: Oh, forgot to remove it. Updated it.